# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function table() in eval()'d code on line 1 Laravel Artisan Tinker

Tags: php, laravel-5, homestead, laravel-artisan

I'm having a problem with learning Laravel so I decided to follow a tutorial at laracast hoping that I could understand something at the end,

I installed homestead and "SSh"ed into my VM and into "~/Code/Laravel" and tried to work with tinker as they did on the tutorial ,, Tinker works but wont execute any command not even a simple selection like (>>> DB:table('projects')-get()) , but keeps giving me the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function table() in eval()'d code on line 1
```

[screen shot of the terminal attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9s1Y.png)
I can run simple mathematical operations and echo commands, but noting related to database, although I migrated the table (projects) successfully, and I was planing to seed it through tinker (by seed I mean input some data into it - is that what seed means in the first place? -).

my OS is Ubuntu if it matters!

thank you in advance!

Comment: even if `table()` (or `tabel()`) was defined, it'd still be wrong. you're doing TWO function calls and subtracting the results. that code is `DB::table() MINUS get()`. you probably want `...->get()` (note the `>`).

Comment: Aswell you probably want `DB::table('card')->get()` (2 double dots, not just one as in your image) - like this you call static methods

Comment: Just took a quick look on the docs: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/280/interacting-with-your-application - theres nothing like DB:: or table() they just use User::find(1) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the attached screen shot. The solution is simple. Instead of

```
DB:table('card')-get();
```

you need to write

```
DB::table('card')->get();
```